# Using Rails helper in Angular template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using Rails with AngularJS and I would like to use rails helper and erb-style `if` statement in an Angular template.

I am displaying a delete button and want to make sure only the owner can see this button.

In a normal `erb` file, I would write:

```
<% if @article.id == current_user.id %>
  <button>Delete</button>
<% end %>
```

I attempted to add `erb` extension to my template files, but I could not use embedded ruby syntax, nor the helper `current_user`.

Another approach I took was adding `ng-show='owner'` to the button, and define `owner` function in the Angular controller to determine if the current user is the owner. But this did not work as I don't have access to `current_user`.

Any suggestions? If there is a more Angular way to do this, I would also like to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think one of the hardest things with AngularJS is switching to a mindset of "data retrieved from the server" not "data available directly in the server".

That is, you need to abandon the idea that you can use any rails-like conventions in your template (same goes for Django or PHP or any other framework).

Instead, think of how you can add an API to your Rails code that returns the data in question in a clean JSON format. Then write an angular service that calls it, say `ArticleService.get(id)`, and then your angular template will be straightforward.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I added a boolean `is_author` to the json response from rails api, and used it with `ng-show` to make it work.

Comment: That's it - you got it :)